# Django app not showing up on 127(...)/admin/

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

http://www.sitepoint.com/build-to-do-list-30-minutes/

So I was doing this (http://www.sitepoint.com/build-to-do-list-30-minutes/) tutorial and everyting went OK. but now I'm stuck because todo.py isn't showing up on the webpage. I have no idea why because I did exactly what they did in the the tutorial. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my crystal ball is hazy today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I skimmed the tutorial you linked to, and the only odd thing I noticed was the `Admin` class:

```
class Item(models.Model): 
    ...
    class Admin: 
        pass
```

I've never heard about it before, but saw other sources mentioning it (such as [djangobook](http://www.djangobook.com/en/beta/chapter06/)). I wonder if it's a feaure introduced in recent versions (or, maybe a very old, already deprecated feature). Check if the version of Django you're using support this feature.

The other way I know of adding admin support is creating a file called `admin.py` in your app folder, and registering the models explicitly:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from gtd.todo.models import Item

admin.site.register(Item)
```

Try that, and see if it works for your case. For more info, I'd suggest checking an up-to-date version of [djangobook](http://www.djangobook.com/) or the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/).

**Edit**: apparently I skimmed too fast that I didn't notice the date in the top of the page: October 11, 2006. So, I'm betting on a deprecated feature...

Comment: That initial syntax for the admin is v old now - pre Django 1.0. The example you give is the way to go

Comment: I'm sorry for asking a vague question, but the point actually was I didn't know what was happening. That was probably the reason the question was'vague, incomplete, ambiguos, overly broad or rhetorical" Luckily I found the answer myself and it was adding admin.py as mgibsonbr already said. After that it worked. Thank you and. And my apologies for asking a vague question, but if you have no idea, how can you phrase an exact question?